# How to check for the first number inside a tuple inside a list?

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

I am trying to modify only the first numbers of the tuples inside the list, I've tried both `==` and `is` to no avail.

```
my_list = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4)]


def print_first_num_of_tuple(list_arg):
    for pair in list_arg:
        for num in pair:
            if num is pair[0]:  # how to check if the number is the first one in the tuple?
                print(num)


print_first_num_of_tuple(my_list)  # prints 1 1 4 4 5 instead of 1 1 4 5
```

Comment: You could just unpack the first element with something like `for first, *rest in list_arg:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the numbers, just index it directly:

```py
for pair in list_arg:
    print(pair[0])
```